# MongoJack support @javax.persistance.Id doesn't work

Tags: java, mongodb, mongojack

I am using MongoJack (2.0.0) to serialize/deserialize objects from MongoDB. According http://mongojack.org/index.html MongoJack should support @javax.persistance.Id.

I have annotated object variable with @Id

```
@Id
private String id;
```

When I try to save the object with a valid id

```
jacksonDBCollection.save(myEntity);
```

The object is saved as new document instead of updating the existing one.

I do use custom deserializer but no serializer in my module:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addDeserializer(MyEntity.class, new MyEntityJsonDeserializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);

return objectMapper;
```

I have debugged some code and see that the id is treated as String instead of ObjectId when calling jacksonDBCollection.save(myEntity). It looks that support for @javax.persistance.Id doesn't work.

I have tried to find the source where this is supported but no luck. Can anyone point me the source where this is supported and/or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: I have created a workaround with a Serializer.

Answer (score 2):

When you are configuring your objectMapper you should also invoke:

```
MongoJackModule.configure(objectMapper);
```

to register [MongoAnnotationIntrospector](https://github.com/devbliss/mongojack/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mongojack/internal/MongoAnnotationIntrospector.java#L68) which detects and interprets the `@javax.persistance.Id` annotation.

Comment: MongoJackModule is part of the org.mongojack.internal package that is not exposed in OSGi context. I did forget to mention that I use OSGi as it was not relevant for this question. Internal indicates that is shouldn't be called directly. Any idea how to configure this differently?

Comment: Briljant! I was grinding my teeth on why `collection.updateById()` wasn't updating any document. This solved the isue.